# Real-life applications/examples of transfer learning approaches

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, computer-vision, transfer-learning

I recently read a nice, informative paper titled ['A Survey on Transfer Learning'](https://www.cse.ust.hk/~qyang/Docs/2009/tkde_transfer_learning.pdf). It mentions 3 settings of transfer learning - inductive, transductive, and unsupervised. At the same time, it states there are 4 common approaches on "what knowledge to transfer" for each setting - instances, features, model parameters, or relations.
I looked up the descriptions of each category, but I do not understand exactly how they are utilised in the domains of Computer Vision and NLP. Could I get an example application of each of these categories to understand better how exactly they differ from each other? How does one determine which approach to use in which setting? [image: TL: Settings and approaches]